# How to install react-native-windows in UWP in visual studio 2017?

Tags: react-native, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I want to use react native in UWP. I have gone through many links but I couldn't find any that I can follow. Can someone give me the steps to install react native and use it in UWP with Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search finally I found a link and I am sharing it here.
https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-for-windows-ba23a4be90b6